# Decreasing size of the PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have an application that the user can upload some pdf files, but generally the pdf's that are send have images with large resolution and size which make the pdf be heavy, I wonder if theres a way to get a pdf get images within compress the images and reassemble the pdf with the new compressed images?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope that you make your users aware that you change their pdfs, I personally hate it when I get an altered pdf back.

Comment: I know but they send pdfs with 5mb that have only 3 pages.